# Typescript: Multiple possible interfaces as an interface

Tags: typescript, interface

If I have a variable like this:

```
let x: number | string | undefined;
```

Is it possible to create an interface that supports all these types? Something like:

```
let x: MyCustomInterface;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, interfaces do not support unions inside of themselves. You can make a type alias though:

```
type MyCustomType = number | string | undefined;
let x: MyCustomType;
```